# How do I preserve \n in quotes

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm trying to preserve the \n so it prints it instead of bash interpreting it as a newline. I'm writing to a screen that runs a server that needs to use the \n to start a newline in that server.
Calling LOGINMESSAGE like this

```
LOGINMESSAGE="Welcome to the server $INITPLAYER! \n Type !HELP for chat commands"

as_user "screen -p 0 -S $SCREENID -X stuff $'/server_message_to info \"$INITPLAYER\" \"$LOGINMESSAGE\"\n'"
```

In the screen I need it to say this /server_message_to info info $INITPLAYER! "Welcome to the server $INITPLAYER! \n Type !HELP for chat commands". So in the screen in needs to keep the \n. Currently it removes it or breaks the command to the game. So basicly what I'm trying to do is have it type to the screen exactly like that keeping the \n in tact.

EDIT: Fixed thanks to chepner

Comment: How are you using `LOGINMESSAGE`? The string itself *does* contain a backslash and an `n`, not a newline.

Comment: Why are you using `$'...'` in the first place? That's what replaces `\n` with a newline character.

Comment: Don't know really. Been editing what I had. How do I change it from $'...' to however to fix it so it keeps the \n.

Comment: It's actually simpler that it seems :) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `LOGINMESSAGE` ends up being evaluated inside a `$'...'`-quoted string, where the `\n` pair is converted to a newline. To prevent that, simply move all but the final `\n` outside the `$'...'`. The shell automatically concatenates strings that are not separated by whitespace.

```
as_user "screen ... '/server_message_to info \"$INITPLAYER\" \"$LOGINMESSAGE\"'$'\n'"
```

Comment: What does "call $LOGINMESSAGE" mean? It's a variable, not a function. You need to edit your question to show exactly what you expect to see. It's not clear what should happen with so many layers of quoting and execution involved.

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for the herp derpness of me explaining this lol. Was trying to figure out how to explain it.